# Jenkins Multi select Parameter to send files to Multiple service with Send over ssh plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a jenkins job which publishes files to some servers.
I have created a extended choice parameter with server names.
Eg:
Basic Parameter Type -> Paramter Type [Multiselect] -> Values (server1,server2,server3,server) -> delimiter (,).
Which shows correctly on job and I am able to select multiple servers from the choice list.

And I have successfully configured these servers in "Publish over SSH" plugin.

When I select only one server from the list, It works fine,
But when I make multiple selections the job fails and doesn't send any files to selected servers.

Console Output :

```
20:01:28 SSH: Skipping [server1] - Label [server1] does not match expression [server1,server3]
20:01:28 SSH: Skipping [server2] - Label [server2] does not match expression [server1,server3]
20:01:28 SSH: Skipping [server3] - Label [server3] does not match expression [server1,server3]
```

Please help on how to select multiple options using the plugin.

Comment: where do you configure the expression? maybe the help text (the `?` button) describes how to make an "or" expression?

Comment: I haven't configured the experssion,
I have passed the choice parameter name in Publishoverssh-> AdvanceSettings->Parameterized publishing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help page says

> ### Parameterized publishing
>
> Publish to servers by matching labels against a regular expression
> provided by a parameter or an environment variable.
>
> For each server the label will be matched against the expression, and
> if matched, the publish will continue, otherwise that server will be
> skipped. If a label is not set for a server it will default to the
> empty string. Configured labels have whitespace removed from the start
> and end of them, which means that an all whitespace label will be
> evaluated as an empty string. The same label can be used multiple
> times, e.g. UAT for a database server and again for the web server.
> The regular expression syntax is the java syntax.
>
> The labels can use the standard Jenkins environment variables e.g.
> $NODE_NAME, or build variables such as a matrix axis.
>
> #### Parameter name
>
> The name of the parameter or environment variable that will contain
> the expression for matching the labels.

This means you have to convert your comma-separated list into a Regular Expression.

You can try to use delimiter `|` in the Basic Parameter type, that means "or" in RegEx.

Comment: Sure, Thankyou for the details,
I tried using "|" delimiter value, its not accepting it as a delimiter. 
Checking more on what values does it accept.

Comment: Sorry, My bad.. you're right.
We have to pass delimiter value as "|" 
The source values will still be "," comma separated to be displayed correctly.

But the expression will contain "|", just checked and it woks.
Thankyou so much.. :)